# Setting size of dialogue in angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

Folks I am using the ui.bootstrap.dialog module.

My question is how do I set the size of the modal window.
I have tried the following but it doesn't work as intended:

```
$scope.viewopts = {
dialogClass: 'dialogsize',
dialogOpenClass:'dialogsize', 
    templateUrl: 'template/view-add-dialogue.tpl.html',   
    controller: 'CustomViewModalCtrl',
   resolve: {
    headerlist: $scope.data         
   }

};
```

Where the class `dialogsize` is defined as in my css file:

```
.dialogsize {
   width: 800px; 
  height: 600px
 }
```

Can anyone assist me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't have anything to do with angularJS, since it just leverages the modal from twitter bootstrap. You just need to override the default value of dialog's size in twitter bootsrap:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/f95ab89fb1da85ff0fcb95c43d4fe4af359e302a/less/modals.less#L130

Regarding the question you ask about customized version of dialog, you can look into its API. We can use our own dialog, which means you can add custom class with css you want.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/dialog

Comment: yes that could be one way, but my application uses a lot of modals so i want to be able to set different sizes. What I was wondering is that is the method that I am using totally off or am I thinking in the right direction ?